Bitcoin Core: "Increasing transaction fee failed (Unable to create transaction. Insufficient funds)"
I sent a RBF transaction, and it's in the mempool. I'd like to increase the fee so it confirms sooner. ¿Why does Bitcoin Core say:

Increasing transaction fee failed (Unable to create transaction. Insufficient funds)

I had "Subtract fee from amount" selected when I sent the original transaction, so why can't it subtract the fee from the amount when I attempt to create a new, higher fee transaction?

Subtract fee from amount is an applied to coin selection when the transaction is created, however this option is not remembered afterwards. Once coin selection is completed, the wallet no longer remembers that subtract fee from amount was used. It also doesn't remember which outputs are the recipients and the amounts that they were expected to originally receive. So when you try to bump its fee, the wallet will not know to take the fee from the recipient.
